# Google Maps API FusionTablesLayer alter styles based on user input

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

This is my first question on SO, so apologies if I leave anything out, but I have searched and haven't been able to come up with an answer.

I am trying to build a small map app using Fusion Tables and the Maps API for local authority level data in England.

The table has a number of columns which can then be combined into an overall score using user-inputted weights. It is this overall score that I would like to be able to map by local authority. So something like 0.5 * Col1 + 0.25 * Col2 + 0.25 * Col3, or however they like. I can make this info show up in the infoWindow pretty easily, as below:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
      infoWindow.setContent((e.row['Col1'].value*weight1 + e.row['Col2'].value*weight2  + weight3*e.row['Col3'].value ))
        ;
      infoWindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
      infoWindow.open(map);
    })
```

However, I would also like to be able to colour the local authority polygons on a gradient according to this calculated score. I have seen this technique for using conditionals to format the colour of polygons:

http://w3facility.org/question/in-fusion-tables-can-a-gradient-be-set-via-the-google-maps-javascript-based-api/

```
styles: [{
  where: "'Col1' > 200",
  polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: '#FFF000',
      fillOpacity: 1
  }
  }, 

  {where: "'Col1'  < 200",
  polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
      fillOpacity: 1
  }
}
  ]
```

However, I have tried and can't seem to use the "weight1" etc variables in here (presumably because it's a request to Fusion Tables, not something calculated at the browser level).

What I would like to know is whether anyone knows any way around this, to be able to dynamically combine columns to affect style according to user-input? I guess one other way to do it would be to send a column to the Fusion Table based on the user input and then call it back and compare, but I can't find how to do this either.

Thanks so much for your help.

C

Comment: When the "user-input" is really a free choice and not an item  of a predefined set of possible values I don't think that it's possible

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle. My current workaround is to draw down the geometry information from the table in a request, then make a separate polygon for each one, which can be custom coloured. I'm also going to try and add a transparent Fusion Tables layer as well to power the info windows.